# How to see/edit/Avoid duplicates in scrapy?

Tags: python, duplicates, scrapy

I was just wondering how I can reset the dupefilter process to avoid a certain number of url to be filtered. 
Indeed, I tested a crawler many times before succeeding, and now that I want to run it with something like `scrapy crawl quotes -o test_new.csv  -s JOBDIR=crawls/quotes_new-1`

It keeps telling me that some url are duplicated and then not visited..

- Would be definitely OK to remove all url from that crawler
- Would appreciate to know where the duplicate url are filtered (then I could edit?)
- The request No-filter is not possible with my problem because it will loop

I can add my code but as it's a general question I felt it would be more confusing than anything. Just ask if you need it :)

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set scrapys `DUPEFILTER_CLASS` setting with your own dupefilter class or just extend the default `RFPDupeFilter`([source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.3/scrapy/dupefilters.py)) class with your changes.

This documentation [pages explains a bit more](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class):

> The default (RFPDupeFilter) filters based on request fingerprint using the scrapy.utils.request.request_fingerprint function.
>
> In order to change the way duplicates are checked you could subclass RFPDupeFilter and override its request_fingerprint method. This method should accept scrapy Request object and return its fingerprint (a string).

Comment: Thanks ! It's a bit complex to me, but I will figure it out !